# how to mount img file (Virtually) WITHOUT loop or fuse or any loadable module in ubuntu 14.04 (running in docker without priviledge in c9.io)

Tags: boot, kernel, mount, virtualization, fstab

I am trying to mount (plain-ext4-format) .img files in a ubuntu 14.04 running in c9.io without ability to load module or kernel tweak or fstab tweak (because it ignores fstab).i can login as root.
i tried-:

1. loop - (kernel don't know about loop devices or load it)
2. fuse - (same)
3. qemu-nbd - ( can't add/load nbd module)
4. qemu-system-x86_64 - (booted ubuntu 14.04 instance successfully but damn slow even with -smp 8  (cpu-8) option, my host has cpu 8)
5. user-mode-linux - ( i think it starts graphic mode, "i want text only mode!!!" i hope this is somethig i can get success with).

so please tell me any non-priviledge and fully fake or Virtual but working method to mount a disk image file with read-write access. or is there any reverse mount function from qemu or similar. or any script to make img file use as if that is a folder !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't mount without some cooperation from the kernel, period.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/896632)

Comment: @MrShunz it does, and the answer is "you can't"

Comment: Thanks muru, can you please delete/edit your answer !!! So some one els can try to find a way to do that !!! :)

Comment: @SheikhRameez edit it to what? A lie?

Comment: See, i can login as root, and can manipulate many things in system except kernel and block device or fuse ! Thats why i am saying to make your answer more reliable instead just "you can't"  !

Comment: @SheikhRameez But what if the answer is that you can't?

Comment: Can i divert/pipe system read-write call to read-write from/into .img file using dd with some script, but how !!!

Comment: @SheikhRameez you're only root in the limited scope of your container, so no, that's not going to make any difference. If you can't affect the kernel, your root privileges are useless here and the answer is still "you can't". Whether I say that with 10 words or a hundred, the answer remains the same.

Comment: @SheikhRameez if you can code, you can use libguestfs to access various filesystems without mounting them.

Comment: Anyway, that site is dead now.